# How can I find "signed payload" from Bigcommerce API

Tags: php, silex, bigcommerce

I used https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex for Develop Bigcommerce APP.

When I install and launch APP from "My draft Apps" after that it's redirect on other domain.

But, GET request not contain "signed payload". So get error "Invalid signed_payload." (GET request contain code,context and scope)

How can I find "signed payload" ? and how to add "signed payload" in GET Request ?

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving the proper GET request parameters if you are installing your app into a store.  The `signed_payload` is not something you will receive until after your app has been properly installed by generating an oAuth API token.

When you first install an app into a store, it is the "Auth Callback Request" that will be sent out which includes the `code`, `context`, and `scope`.  Using those 3 values, and 4 others that you have already, you can then make a POST request to the BC Auth service (`https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2/token`) to generate an API token.  Once that has been done successfully your app is now installed.  Here is the BC documentation that covers in detail the "Auth Callback Request" parameters and the POST request details to generate an oAuth API token for a store:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/callback

After install has been completed successfully, and once you have refreshed your Control Panel page, you will see your app appear as an icon in the "Apps" menu.  Clicking your app at that point will generate the "Load Callback Request" which is what contains a `signed_payload` query parameter, as described on this page:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/load

So it appears that you may have not entered the proper Auth Callback URL into your app settings as noted in the instructions of that PHP Silex example app.  They state you should be using `http://localhost:8000/auth/callback` by default as your "Auth Callback URL".  If you were instead using `http://localhost:8000/load` as your "Auth Callback URL" then that would result in the error you are seeing.

The above would be true if you are using the default example and you are able to receive the Auth Callback Request into your "Load Callback" application path even though it is using just plain HTTP.  Normally apps require a full HTTPS path for the Auth and Load Callbacks to work at all.

I hope this helps, do add some more details about your setup if you need further assistance.  Such as what do you have set as your "Auth Callback URL" in your BC App settings?  And did you change the default PHP Silex code at all?

Comment: Thanks for reply.

After redirect get below error:

Something went wrong... [400] {"error":"redirect_uri_mismatch","error_description":"Parameter redirect_uri does not match registered URI"}

Comment: That error implies that an incorrect `redirect_uri` value is being sent in your POST.  Since that is an environment value that you set manually you should make sure the redirect URI you are entering matches what you have in your app settings.

On this line you see where the `redirect_uri` is set - (https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex/blob/master/index.php#L33).  This is the function that is called - (https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex/blob/master/index.php#L91-L95). What value are you setting for the `BC_CALLBACK_URL` environment variable?

Comment: I had set 'redirect_uri' manually which set in my app setting
'redirect_uri' => "http://localhost/bcapp1/",

Now I get below error:

"CredisException in Client.php line 430: Connection to Redis failed after 1 failures.Last Error : (10061) No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Comment: @Gunjan - That new error is a failure for the app to connect to the Redis database on your system.  You should make sure that server is working or remove the usage of the Redis from the app altogether.  It is definitely not necessary to store the results of your POST request to generate an API token within memory.  You can just read the response directly and then utilize the API token to authenticate when making API calls.